# How to create OpenCV Map from NumPY Array?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a NumPY array which maps input pixels to output pixels, like so:

```
>>> arr
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2]],

       [[2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2]]])
```

I wish to use this as the input to OpenCV's [`remap`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#void%20remap(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20map1,%20InputArray%20map2,%20int%20interpolation,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue)) method. I've tried using it directly like so:

```
>>> cv2.remap(input_image, arr, None, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

However this throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 149, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 142, in main
    cv2.INTER_LINEAR
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:1820: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ((map1.type() == CV_32FC2 || map1.type() == CV_16SC2) && map2.empty()) || (map1.type() == CV_32FC1 && map2.type() == CV_32FC1) in function 'remap'
```

How do I convert from a NumPY array to a `CV_32FC2` or `CV_16SC2`?

Comment: `arr.astype(np.float32)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang That was a lot easier than I thought it would be

Comment: FYI - `32FC2` means "32 bit - floating point - 2 channels" i.e. a `NxMx2` array of type float32. And `16SC2` means "16 bit - signed integer - 2 channels" , so signed short type.

Comment: I figured the “32F” referred to a 32-bit floating point number, but the “CV_” had me thinking this was an OpenCV structure. I was looking for something like `cv2.fromarray`. I didn’t realize I could just pass it a NumPY array with the proper types.